# Displaying background both on top and bottom of a div? #multiple background-position

Tags: django, css

i need to get this little gray rectangle (red circle) to be displayed both on top n bottom of a div that coitains thumbnails (btw this div might aswell cointain 2 or 3 rows of thumbnails)

Picture:

[image: 2x borders?]

here is my code for how it looks atm:

```
.jq_thumbnails {
    background: url("/site_media/static/coffee_small_top.png") top left no-repeat;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect easily? I thought of making ifequal tag that would check the length of thumbnails list and use a certain background picture accordingly, but maybe it is possible to achieve this using html/css only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can leverage [CSS3 Multiple Background Images](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/):

```
.jq_thumbnails {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-top.png), url(../images/bg-bottom.png);
    background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom;
}
```

Set the `background-repeat` property to suit your particular scenario:

```
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
```

This is [supported in](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) all current versions of the major browsers:

Comment: added background-repeat: no-repeat; to your code and it works perfectly, thanks man, google didnt return anything useful when I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can make an outer div and an inner one that covers the background, so you can `repeat-y` the background ;)